# Agregar fuente personalizada al diseñador de Visual Studio sin necesidad de instalarla

Tags: visual-studio, windows, fuentes

Mi duda es:
¿Puedo desde el diseñador de un proyecto de c# escoger un tipo de fuente que no tenga instalada en windows pero tenga en una carpeta del proyecto?

Aquí se ve la carpeta con las fuentes **sin instalar.**

[image: proyecto]

En Font no puedo escoger ninguna de las fuentes de la carpeta `Fonts`.

[image: propiedades fuente]

Mi pregunta es ¿Se puede seleccionar una fuente de esa carpeta `Fonts` sin instalarla en windows desde el diseñador? y si es así ¿Cómo?

Comment: Yo no conozco ni creo que sea posible seleccionar una fuente no instalada desde el diseñador. Pero si se podría hacer por código, usando por ejemplo [PrivateFontCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: muchas gracias @Pikoh pero la idea es hacerlo sin código :)

Comment: Entonces, lamentablemente me temo que la respuesta es "no es posible"